# Scala type class can't find implicit instances

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am trying to create a type class in Scala and use it to make a simple polymorphic case class. This example doesn't compile and gives "could not find implicit value for parameter writer:A$A228.this.ValueWriter[T]". I can't really figure out what could be going wrong or where to start.

```
trait Keeper

case class StringKeeper(measure: String) extends Keeper

case class StringLengthKeeper(measure: Int) extends Keeper


trait ValueWriter[A] {
  def write(value: String): A
}

object DefaultValueWriters {
  implicit val stringWriter = new ValueWriter[StringKeeper] {
    def write(value: String) = StringKeeper(value)
  }
  implicit val stringLengthWriter = new ValueWriter[StringLengthKeeper] {
    def write(value: String) = StringLengthKeeper(value.length)
  }
}

object Write {
  def toWrite[A](value: String)(implicit writer: ValueWriter[A]) = {
    writer.write(value)
  }
}


case class WriterOfKeepers[T <: Keeper](value: String) {

  def run: T = {
    Write.toWrite[T](value)
  }

}

import DefaultValueWriters._

val writerLengthKeeper = WriterOfKeepers[StringLengthKeeper]("TestString")

writerLengthKeeper.run
```

Comment: `run` can't choose the implicit dynamically; you have to supply it from the call site that knows what `T` is, either a ctor param or a param to `run`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no implicit `ValueWriter` in scope when you call `Write.toWrite`.

You need to have the implicit parameter in the constructor

```
case class WriterOfKeepers[T <: Keeper : ValueWriter](value: String) {

  def run: T = {
    Write.toWrite[T](value)
  }

}
```

or in the method

```
case class WriterOfKeepers[T <: Keeper](value: String) {

  def run(implicit writer: ValueWriter[T]): T = {
    Write.toWrite(value)
  }

}
```

or find some other way compatible with your requirements (and I don't know those).

Comment: Wow! That did the trick. What does the syntax `[T <: Keeper: ValueWriter]` mean. The relationship between Keeper and Value Writer here, denoted by a ":", is mysterious to me. I have some googling to do. EDIT: Ah, I see it's the same as `WriterOfKeepers[T <: Keeper](value: String)(implicit vwriter: ValueWriter[T]`)

Comment: @user44450, yep. I should've said that, but I'm glad you found it :)